# How can I replace html with jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, string, replace

I have the following code:

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs-wrapper">
   <li>Link A (one)</li>
   <li>Link A <span style="font-size:10px">(two)</span></li>
   <li>Link B</li>
   <li>Link C</li>
</ul>
```

My goal:
Eliminating the span within the second li with pure jQuery.

My desired outcome:

```
 <ul class="breadcrumbs-wrapper">
    <li>Link A (one)</li>
    <li>Link A (two)</li>
    <li>Link B</li>
    <li>Link C</li>
 </ul>
```

My attempt so far:

```
var replaced = jQuery(".breadcrumbs-wrapper").html().replace(/<span style="font-size:10px">(two)</span>/g,'(two)');
jQuery(".breadcrumbs-wrapper").html(replaced);
```

What is wrong here?
How do I need to adapt the code?

JSFIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/g6b82qya/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DOM and not strings. unwrap is what you want to use.

```js
$(".breadcrumbs-wrapper li span[style]").contents().unwrap()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="breadcrumbs-wrapper">
   <li>Link A (one)</li>
   <li>Link A <span style="font-size:10px">(two)</span></li>
   <li>Link B</li>
   <li>Link C</li>
</ul>
```